# Launch/Test VS Emulator for Android in/from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I've noticed that Visual Studio has a separate/independent VS Emulator for Android, but I can't figure out how to launch/test their emulator directly from Visual Studio Code. Has anyone used it before? Can anyone tell me how to connect/launch the emulator in/from VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

there is a marketplace plugin for that:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=343max.android-emulator-launcher

launch via
Cmd-Shit-P > Launch Android Emulator

you can also create a task to do it:
https://gist.github.com/wbroek/a2caf1ace90eac0c5e25497548f41a6e

and put the task in your debug pipeline (see this: https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/android-debugging-with-visual-studio-code-r4820/).  this will launch the emulator.  to have the emulator open to whatever you're doing, it depends on the framework, etc.  For instance, React Native you can use expo for "realtime" updating/debugging (basically just an app that lives on the phone and proxies the compiled code).  For full "automated" pipeline, you'd need a task to build your apk, upload it to the phone, then launch apk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I Don't think the task does the deal. I need the Microsoft emulators and not the android sdk ones. These target the android ones and it is only available for the Mac.

Comment: ah so this guy?
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Go about a third down the page here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studios-emulator-for-android/

Create a task to launch via CLI.  Again, you can add the task to your debug / launch (e.g. compound configuration... see https://electrondevtips.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/setting-up-multi-target-compound-debugging-in-vs-code/  looks like a good example of what I'm gettin' at.

Comment: thnx, will checkout

Comment: FYI plugin has memo: "This is only going to work on macOS."

Comment: Is there a solution for Windows, too?